# JMeter : Recording traffic swing to servlet

Tags: jmeter

I have got swing app which calls JBoss deployed applicaton servlet.
I was testing [JMeter Recording](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) but as far as i know this approach requires browser to send requests. 
Is it possible to record traffic from another kinds on clients (ie. swing) using JMeter?

What I need is a way to see **incoming** http requests to JBoss server.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You can configure your swing app to use JMeter's proxy server - it'll allow to record what you want.

See [Java Networking and Proxies](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html) in order to learn how to configure your swing application to use JMeter's proxy server and [Load Testing Mobile Apps. But Made Easy.](http://blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-mobile-apps-made-easy) guide to get the whole idea on how you should set up your recording environment, just substitute mobile device with your swing app.

Hope this helps.